# How to get the values inside an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$playerId= array();
$playerId[] = intval($row['Id']);
$allrounders[] = array(
        'Weight'=>$fullTotal,
    'Id'=>$playerId
);
rsort($allrounders);
$sliceAr = array_slice($allrounders,0,5);
foreach($sliceAr as $allroundK){
         echo $allrounders[]['Id']."<br/>";

}
```

Question: 
In the above array how to get the values of the Id Key accordingly? It takes all the player scores and organizes that with his ID and sorts it descending order. It takes the 1st 5 results. I need the Ids of those.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the foreach loop, `$allroundK` is the item of your array. In this case, it's the array with weight and id. So:

```
foreach($sliceAr as $allroundK) {
    echo $allroundK['Id']."<br />";
}
```

Comment: From that i only got array , array, array in the result

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
echo $allrounders[0]['Id'][0];
```

Since you have set the array in this manner

```
$allrounders[] = array(
    'Weight'=>$fullTotal,
    'Id'=>$playerId
);
```

Here `$allrounders[]` also means that an array so the elements Weight and Id will be added in the [0th] element of the array `$allrounders`

If you want to get rid of [0] just set the array like this

```
$allrounders = array(
    'Weight'=>$fullTotal,
    'Id'=>$playerId
);
```

And now you can access the `Id` like

```
echo $allrounders['Id'][0];
```

**EDIT:**

In your case it will work as

```
foreach($sliceAr as $allroundK){
    echo $allroundK['Id'][0]."<br/>";
}
```

or

```
foreach($sliceAr as $allroundK){
    foreach($allroundK['Id'][0] as $allroundJ){
        echo $allroundJ."<br/>";
    }
}
```